# How to write Test class for pagereference

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class PaginationMultiPages {

    public Account acc{get;Set;}

    public PaginationMultiPages(){
        acc=new Account();
    }

    public PageReference next1(){
        return page.pagenationVfPage2;
    }
    public PageReference next2(){
        return page.pagenationVfPage3;
    }
    public PageReference previous1(){
        return page.pagenationVfPage1;
    }
    public PageReference previous2(){
        return page.pagenationVfPage2;
    }
    public void  save(){
        upsert acc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get some ideas from the below listed sites :

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BPyoIAG

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2015/11/how-to-cover-pagereference-method-in.html

http://force-salesforce.blogspot.in/2011/08/testing-pagereference-in-controllers-in.html

http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.in/2011/08/writing-unit-tests-for-pagereference.html

**Sample Apex Class:**

```
public class Sample {
    public Sample() {
    }

    public PageReference goToSFSE() {
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('https://salesforce.stackexchange.com');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@isTest
private class SampleTest {
    @isTest static void test() {
        Sample s = new Sample();
        s.goToSFSE();
    }
}
```